# Embed webpage into another webpage

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to embed a webpage into another webpage without using iframe? I tried using iframe but the browser keeps blocking it because of "X-Frame options / Content Security Policy". Thank you.

Comment: You can load Webpage using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the page using the load method.  For more details, please refer reference link
https://api.jquery.com/load/

#result: in below example is your div tag id in that page content load.

```
 $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
```

Comment: I need to embed a different website, and it's hosted in local.

Comment: Out of the box: no. It's a security issue. There are a few different workarounds though:https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/